# Unity gizmo outlines show doubles?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, renderer, unity-webgl

We are working with Unity 2020.3.8 and have set up custom outlines via Unity gizmos using the following:

```
public GizmoLine(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, Color color)
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
            Color = color;
        }

 public void OnRenderObject()
        {
            if (GizmoLines.Count == 0) return;
            
            GizmoLines.Clear();
            WireframeHandler.UpdateWireframes();
            
            // Apply the line material
            _lineMaterial.SetPass(0);

            // Draw lines
            GL.PushMatrix();
            GL.Begin(GL.LINES);
            foreach (var gizmoLine in GizmoLines)
            {
                GL.Color(gizmoLine.Color);
                DrawLineWithThickness(gizmoLine);
            }
            GL.End();
            GL.PopMatrix();
        }


        private static void CreateLineMaterial()
        {
            if (_lineMaterial) return;
            
            // Unity has a built-in shader that is useful for drawing
            // simple colored things.
            var shader = Shader.Find("Hidden/Internal-Colored");
            _lineMaterial = new Material(shader)
            {
                hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave
            };
            // Turn on alpha blending
            _lineMaterial.SetInt("_SrcBlend", 
                (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
            _lineMaterial.SetInt("_DstBlend", 
                (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
            // Turn backface culling off
            _lineMaterial.SetInt("_Cull", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.CullMode.Off);
            // Turn off depth writes
            _lineMaterial.SetInt("_ZWrite", 0);
        }


        private void DrawLineWithThickness(GizmoLine line)
        {
            var lineCount = (1 + Mathf.CeilToInt(lineThickness)) * lineMultiplier;
            if (lineCount == 1)
            {
                GL.Vertex(line.A);
                GL.Vertex(line.B);
            }
            else
            {
                var screenPoint1 = _mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(line.A);
                var screenPoint2 = _mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(line.B);
                
                var v1 = (screenPoint2 - screenPoint1).normalized;
                var normal = Vector3.Cross(v1, Vector3.forward);
                for (var i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
                {
                    var tempOrigin = 
                        normal * lineThickness * ((float)i / (lineCount - 1) - 0.5f);
                    var trueOrigin = 
                        _mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint1 + tempOrigin);
                    var destination = 
                        _mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint2 + tempOrigin);
                    
                    GL.Vertex(trueOrigin);
                    GL.Vertex(destination);
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Sometimes - not reliably, but sometimes - this results in a second outline being rendered away from the outlined object.

Is this a known issue with Unity gizmos? Is there an additional call to `.Clear()` that should be occurring?

Comment: Should there be a second outline?

Comment: What does `WireframeHandler.UpdateWireframes();` do and how is `GizmoLines` filled? Could this come from multiple cameras?